# How to avoid reading same records from SQL Database from multiple threads in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, linq, async-await

We are processing individual file in multi-threaded environment in windows service where for every 10 seconds a new thread would start processing unprocessed files.

```
await Task.Run(()=> ProcessFilesFromDatabase());
```

At times we face a problem like two threads read same files and we encounter like duplicate files gets processed. When we check for online how to overcome in LINQ to Entities in such cases we were suggested to use **transaction scope and read committed**

```
using (var context = new Context())
        {
            var transActionOption1 = new TransactionOptions();
            transActionOption1.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
            using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transActionOption1))
            
            {

                try
                {
                       var fileInfo = context.File.Where(a=>!a.IsRead).ToList();
                       foreach (FileDetails fileDetail in fileInfo) 
                       {
                           fileDetail.IsRead = true;
                           context.Entry(fileDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
                           context.savechanges();
                       }
                      
                       tran.Complete();
                }
               //Process each file after updating read
            }
          }
```

But still thread 1 read 5 records and before updating back to database with a flag say IsRead - true, thread 2 reads same 5 records.

We believe that with ReadCommitted scope any uncommitted records will not be read by other threads.

Thanks,

Selva

Comment: Why start new thread every 10 seconds for that? Maybe use just one thread and check every 10 seconds to prevent that overlap?

Comment: Yes may be if thread 1 process files for 1 min in the mean time next set of files arrive means we need to wait 60 seconds to process next set of files.

I can new start new thread to start new files or unprocessed files if any if interval was 10 seconds

Comment: Then it's better to let one thread check for new files every 10 seconds, and put things to process in queue (in memory, like `ConcurrentQueue`). Then one or more other threads pull items from this queue and handle them. That will be more easy and reliable than trying to work on the same set of items in database concurrently.

Comment: Almost all of the code is either not needed or actively harmful. A DbContext caches changes and persists all of them in a single transaction when you call `SaveChanges`. It's almost always a *bug* to call SaveChanges after every modification. If you don't do that, you won't need a TransactionScope. As for polling for changes - don't do it like that. There are far better ways, starting with *not* using the database for notifications. And not using an ORM to load changes

Comment: For starters, use a *single* thread to poll the database and have it feed workers eg, through a Channel<T>. SQL Server supports [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) in all versions and editions which allows you to cheaply read any records modified after the last check.

Comment: `ReadCommitted` doesn't mean that other threads can't read the same data, only that they can't read records that are locked for update. By calling `SaveChanges` for individual records you allow *other* queries to read the records that haven't been persisted yet. If you used `SaveChanges` properly, outside the loop, this wouldn't happen. BTW there's no reason to use `context.Entry(fileDetail).State`. EF Core already tracks the entities and will detect any changes to the properties. Of course that doesn't mean conflicts will go away. There's still a chance other threads will read the same data

Comment: *Don't* use EF (or any ORM) for such queries. That's not what they're about. T-SQL offers ways to atomically modify data and return the modified rows in a single statement, eg `UPDATE Files SET IsRead=true OUTPUT inserted.* Where IsRead=false`. UPDATE itself is atomic. The `OUTPUT` clause will return the modified rows only. You can still use EF with the results though, through eg `.FromSqlRaw` and map them to `File` entities

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Which runtime version?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this design:

- EF, and any ORM, aren't suitable for such queries. Calling `SaveChanges` for each row *increases* the chance of collisions.
- Polling *and* processing the data on the same thread almost guarantees there will be collisions from one job execution to the next

**Getting the changes**

In SQL Server it's possible to return modified data from the query that modified them with the OUTPUT clause, eg :

```
UPDATE Files
Set IsRead=1
OUTPUT inserted.*
where IsRead=0;
```

In EF Core it's possible to map the results to an entity with `FromSqlRaw`, eg :

```
List<File> GetNewFiles()
{
    var sql=@"UPDATE Files
Set IsRead=1
OUTPUT inserted.*
where IsRead=0;";
    using(var context=new MyContext())
    {
        var newFiles=context.Files.FromSqlRaw(sql)...ToList();
        return newFiles;
    }
}
```

EF is only used to load the data here. It's probably simpler to use a microORM like Dapper to execute the query and map the results directly

```
List<File> GetNewFiles(string connectionString)
{
    var sql=@"UPDATE Files
Set IsRead=1
OUTPUT inserted.*
where IsRead=0;";
    using(var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var newFiles=connection.Query<File>(sql).ToList();
        return newFiles;
    }
}
```

**Separate polling from processing**

To avoid conflicts altogether, the polling and processing steps should be separated. One way to do that is to publish the poll results to eg an ActionBlock or Channel and have a worker process them.

Let's assume the processing method is `ProcessFiles(List<File>)`. An [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-5.0) can be used to process any files posted to it using that method.

```
var block=new ActionBlock<List<File>>(files=>ProcessFiles(files));
```

A timer can be used to poll the database and post any new files to the block

```
var timer=new Timer(()=>{
    var files=GetNewFiles(connectionString);
    block.Post(files)
});

timer.Change(0,10000);
```

This is enough to start polling the database and process the files in a different database.

To stop processing, first we stop the timer then we tell the block to stop and wait for it to finish:

```
timer.Dispose();
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```